# iPhone to Android Market

Tags: iphone, android, google-play

(I am coming from an iPhone experience)

When we create an iPhone app, Apple gives us a http URL that we can put on web pages that when clicked will open iTunes and give the user a chance to buy on their desktop.

As Android has no "iTunes" Windows/Mac application on the desktop, what do I link to on my Web pages/email marketing so that users can go and buy the Android apps we are writing?

Ian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this link on your site where <packagename> is the name of your android application. It will directly open up the Andorid Market an a Market phone, or it will take a Windows Browser to the details of the android app.

http://market.android.com/details?id=<packagename > or
market://details?id=<packagename>

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. You can put your apk file directly to your homepage. But you can also publish it on the Android market. See this link for a useful guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Comment: If we only wish to sell apps, do we need to only publish in the Market and not host the .apk on our site?

Comment: You could also host it on your site but you would need to create some type of unlock key.